# increment a variable in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

All,

How Can we increment a  value  like the following  in django templates,

```
  {{ flag =0 }}

  {% for op in options %}
   {{op.choices}}<input type="radio" name="template" id="template" value="template{{flag++}}"/>
  {% endfor %}
```

thanks..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think it's intended you should alter data in your templates. For in your specific case, you could instead use the `forloop.counter` variable.

For example:

```
{% for op in options %}
  {{op.choices}}<input type="radio" name="template" id="template{{forloop.counter}}" value="template{{forloop.counter}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Also note that I added that number to the `id` attributes of the `<input />` tag. Otherwise you'll have multiple inputs with the same id.

EDIT: I didn't note that it was a radio input. You could of course have the same name for each `<input type="radio" />`.

Answer (score 9):

You explicitly can't do that in a template. Variable assignment is not allowed.

However if all you want is a counter in your loop, you just need to use `{{ forloop.counter }}`.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look into having Django [forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) produce these values