# What is the best way to get row_num in django?

Tags: python, django, templates

What is the best way to get row_num in django ? Can we use a variable as counter in django template tags ?

```
{% for o in objects %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ row_num }}</td>
  <td>{{ o.first_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ o.last_name }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the forloop template tag :

- forloop.counter -> The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)
- forloop.counter0 -> The current iteration of the loop (0-indexed)
- forloop.revcounter -> The number of iterations from the end of the loop (1-indexed)
- forloop.revcounter0 -> The number of iterations from the end of the loop (0-indexed)
- forloop.first -> True if this is the first time through the loop
- forloop.last -> True if this is the last time through the loop
- forloop.parentloop -> For nested loops, this is the loop "above" the current one

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer here too. I searched for "counter", should've searched for "increment". (I'll accept the answer in about 8 mins, ~.~ ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507284/increment-a-variable-in-django-templates

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using django (I'm using pylons) but I dont think that this is actually a django "problem". You should use "enumerate". It is part of the python language.

Like this:

```
for i, book in enumerate(books): 
    print i+". "+book.name
```

this would print

> 1. Harry Potter
> 2. Lord of the Rings

so in your case you should write:

```
{% for i, o in enumerate(objects) %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ i }}</td>
  <td>{{ o.first_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ o.last_name }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this was what you were looking for.

Best, k.

Comment: -1: You can't use arbitrary Python in Django's template system.

Comment: It was not a "problem", I just wanted to know if there was an easier way to do it in Django. Apparently there is.